# AVL deletion in Mark Allen Weiss 's book

Tags: c++, data-structures, avl-tree

in *data structure and algorithm analysis in C++* 's AVL Tree related chapters,When the author talks about the delete operation of the AVL tree，There's a sentence I can't understand

> For
> instance, case 1 in Figure 4.34, which would now reﬂect a deletion from tree Z (rather than
> an insertion into X), must be augmented with the possibility that tree Y could be as deep
> as tree X.

here is Figure 4.34:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zyF6.png)

Comment: Perhaps google "how do AVL trees work" ?

Comment: I may understand, that is to say, the imbalance caused by deleting nodes will appear  the situation that the left and right subtree have the same depth during rotation, so single-rotation should be preferred over double- rotation.  the word "must" misled me

Comment: change "during rotation"  to  "before rebalance" in previous sentence